# breezejs importEntities fail "this key is already attached"

Tags: local-storage, breeze

I have a SPA (hot towel template) and use `window.localStore` for keep data in browser. I used  export/import from breeze 1.3.3 and those worked perfectly while I cleared browser history in the first time of test, later I didn't clear browser history and those worked fine again export/import entities to `window.localStore`. But later after of many tests the browser show the next error:

```
SCRIPT5022: This key is already attached: Project:#Solution.Project--1
```

The error appeared when I had close the browser and I didn't clear the browser history for first time of test.

When I load the SPA, first I load the data of `window.localStore` and use `importEntities` function of breeze.

The SPA is loaded `manager.getChanges().length` result zero (`0`) and that is correct, later I call the next function `setLocalStorageToManager` to load pending changes in actual manager.

```
function setLocalStorageToManager(manager) {
var name = 'pendingChangesOnLocalStorage';
if (window.localStorage.length > 0) {
    var importData = window.localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (importData) {
        return manager.importEntities(importData,
            { mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges });

    } else {
        return manager;
    }

} else {
    return manager;
}
}
```

The error appeared here:

`manager.importEntities(importData,{ mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges });`

For example in my test the `window.localStore` return two entities with `id:-1` and `id:-2`, but in `breeze.debug.js` in the next function read the first entity with `id:-1`, but later read the second entity with `id:-1` again and It was the error `This key is already attached`:

```
proto.attachEntity = function (entity, entityState) {
    // entity should already have an aspect.
    var ix;
    var aspect = entity.entityAspect;
    var keyInGroup = aspect.getKey()._keyInGroup;
    ix = this._indexMap[keyInGroup];
    if (ix >= 0) {
        if (this._entities[ix] === entity) { //-->Error here
            return entity;
        }
        throw new Error("This key is already attached: " + aspect.getKey());
    }

    if (this._emptyIndexes.length === 0) {
        ix = this._entities.push(entity) - 1;
    } else {
        ix = this._emptyIndexes.pop();
        this._entities[ix] = entity;
    }
    this._indexMap[keyInGroup] = ix;
    aspect.entityState = entityState;
    aspect.entityGroup = this;
    aspect.entityManager = this.entityManager;
    return entity;
};
```

The error appeared in the third test (export data to localStorage and import this data) without delete browser history, I tested in IE10, Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93 m and Firefox 21.0.

Please any help much appreciated